# big query if and dates error

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am creating a if function to check if a string date matches the current year. My next step would be doing a datesub or just showing the regular date.

I am getting following error when trying this IF function in BQ.

> Error in query string: No matching signature for function IF for argument types:BOOL, DATE, BOOL. Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY) at [3:1]

```
 IF(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y",CURRENT_DATETIME())= SUBSTR(date, 0, 4), 
 DATE(cast(SUBSTR(date, 0, 4) AS INT64),cast(SUBSTR(date, 4, 2) AS INT64),cast(SUBSTR(date, 6, 2) AS INT64)), 
 FALSE)
```

Following does work:

```
 IF(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y",CURRENT_DATETIME())= SUBSTR(date, 0, 4),
 TRUE, 
 FALSE)
```

How do I get this working in BQ (standard sql)?

The docs say this which I do not understand and find no clear answers on google from. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions

> true_result and else_result must be coercible to a common supertype.

Thanks

Comment: There are probably simpler ways to do what you want.  Sample data and desired results are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Google SQL refuse to mix return value of type DATE and BOOLEAN !

In your example, the third argument of IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY) is equal to FALSE 
but it must be of type DATE or must be NULL.

```
IF(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y",CURRENT_DATETIME())= SUBSTR(date, 0, 4)
  ,DATE(cast(SUBSTR(date, 0, 4) AS INT64)
       ,cast(SUBSTR(date, 4, 2) AS INT64)
       ,cast(SUBSTR(date, 6, 2) AS INT64)
       )
  ,NULL
  )
```

Comment: This is it, thanks! Quite logical when you think about it afterwards but that might have putten it a bit more down to earth in the docs.

Comment: Yes, since Internet, documentation is not more like before :-) But your problem exists with other SQL function as NVL() or COALESCE() in which all not NULL types must be equal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `case`:

```
(CASE WHEN FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y', CURRENT_DATETIME()) =
           SUBSTR(date, 0, 4), 
      THEN DATE(cast(SUBSTR(date, 0, 4) AS INT64), cast(SUBSTR(date, 4, 2) AS INT64),cast(SUBSTR(date, 6, 2) AS INT64))
 END)
```

I think you could simplify this a bit.  For instance:

```
(CASE WHEN FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y', CURRENT_DATETIME()) = SUBSTR(date, 1, 4), 
      THEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) 
 END)
```